# How to make a file loader in java

Tags: java, file, save, joptionpane, filewriter

I already make a program that save the entered data in the textfields.
It's saving technique is like this

```
data0 = student number
data1 = name
data2 = section
data3 = cp
data4 = email
data5 = address
```

then it saves all the entry in a single line of text like this

```
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
```

but the problem I face is how to load the string and slice the different data and print it in a different textfield where they are designated.

BTW this is my code

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Jfetizanan
 */
public class DATAPROCCESS extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Creates new form processPOINT
     */
    public DATAPROCCESS() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Label1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        StudentNO = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        section = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cp = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        email = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        save = new javax.swing.JButton();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel7.setText("jLabel7");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 102, 255));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setResizable(false);

        Label1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Label1.setText("STUDENT INFO STORAGE v1");

        jLabel1.setText("Student No:");

        jLabel2.setText("Name:");

        jLabel3.setText("Section:");

        jLabel5.setText("Cellphone #:");

        jLabel6.setText("E-Mail:");

        jLabel8.setText("Address:");

        save.setText("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                 File file = new File("data.dat");

                            try {
                                 try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
                                 String data0 = StudentNO.getText();
                                 String data1 = name.getText();
                                 String data2 = section.getText();
                                 String data3 = cp.getText();
                                 String data4 = email.getText();
                                 String data5 = jTextField1.getText();

                                 writer.write(data0+" | "+data1+" | "+data2+" | "+data3+" | "+data4+" | "+data5+"/n");
                                }

                                System.out.println("Data Saved");
                                } catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                                }
                                } 
                                });
        reset.setText("Reset");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3))))
                                .addGap(15, 15, 15))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(save, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 136, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(reset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(StudentNO)
                            .addComponent(name)
                            .addComponent(section)
                            .addComponent(cp)
                            .addComponent(email)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1))
                        .addGap(0, 13, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(StudentNO, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(section, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(cp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(email, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(save)
                    .addComponent(reset))
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DATAPROCCESS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new DATAPROCCESS().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel Label1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField StudentNO;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cp;
    private javax.swing.JTextField email;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField name;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    private javax.swing.JButton save;
    private javax.swing.JTextField section;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to parse the data from data file and load it to the respective fields, you can do these things.
1. Read the contents of a file. You can get an example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml)
2. split the contents using the code below.

> ```
> String delimiter = "|";
> temp = str.split(delimiter);
> for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
>      System.out.println(temp[i]); //you will get data here
> }
> ```

3.Now get the respective text fields and load the respective data

1. Now you are trying to actually search for a data using first field. You can do like this below.

> ```
> try{
>       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
>       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
>       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
>       String strLine;
>       while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
>        if (strLine.startsWith("Give your data0 here")){
>
>                         String delimiter = "|";
>                         temp = str.split(delimiter);
>                         for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
>                           System.out.println(temp[i]); //you will get data here
>                         }
>        }
>       }
>       in.close();
>       }catch (Exception e){
>           System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
>       }
> ```

Comment: data0 contains the unique Student No. I want my loader to search all data0 that matches what I type in the textfield, if it finds a match It will print the the rest of the matched data0's data "data1,data2,data3,data4 and data5" in their corresponding textarea for display 
remember that there may other lines present within the file with different-unique data

Comment: I think you are trying to create a search option throught data0 on a match find it will load other corresponding data, If I have understood you correctly. Now, you are writing the data to file line by line. Is it? If so, then read it line by line, use startswith function in java string_variable.startsWith(your required data i.e you are searching for) and fill the data to respective fields. You can find more about it here http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/StrStartWith.shtml

Comment: Yeah you're write, but how?, I don't know the codes I'm a newbie

Comment: I have given a small example check it.

Comment: One more thing :) How would I make a split function in the searched dat0?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15320/discussion-between-jfetz2191-and-vini)

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( "filename" ), "UTF-8" ) ) );
String line = reader.readLine();
reader.close();
String[] parts = line.split( "\\|", -1 );
```

Note: You shouldn't use `FileWriter` because it uses the "default encoding" - whatever that is. Always use

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( "filename" ), "UTF-8" ) ) );
```

Comment: the data.dat is it's output it has the lines



    `data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5`
    `data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5`
    `data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5`
    `data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5`
    `etc...`

data0 contains the unique Student No. I want my loader to search all data0 that matches what I type in the textfield, if it finds a match It will print the the rest of the matched data0's data "data1,data2,data3,data4 and data5" in their corresponding textarea for display

Comment: And what is your problem? Just use the code above to read line by line.